# Need help to write a query in rethinkdb in java

Tags: java, rethinkdb

I have below sample document:

### People table:

```
{
    "age": "21" ,
    "books": [
        {
            "bookname": "book1" ,
            "createdate": Mon Nov 03 1986 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 ,
            "publisherid": "65bf6fec-13d0-45ae-8ee5-a6ed6a0203b2"
        } ,
        {
            "bookname": "book2" ,
            "createdate": Tue Nov 03 1987 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 ,
            "publisherid": "65bf6fec-13d0-45ae-8ee5-a6ed6a0203b2"
        } ,
        {
            "bookname": "book3" ,
            "createdate": Thu Nov 03 1988 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 ,
            "publisherid": "63fb88f2-8035-4bee-a055-caf77c619e44"
        }
    ] ,
    "id": "a39c572e-b8ae-40c1-83af-393b96c08938" ,
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

and

### publisher

```
{
    "id": "65bf6fec-13d0-45ae-8ee5-a6ed6a0203b2" ,
    "place": "usa" ,
    "publishername": "pub1"
}
{
    "id": "63fb88f2-8035-4bee-a055-caf77c619e44" ,
    "place": "japan" ,
    "publishername": "pub2"
}
```

I am trying to write a query which will do a join on the above tables and give me a result like:

```
{
    "age": "21" ,
    "books": [
        {
            "bookname": "book1" ,
            "createdate": Mon Nov 03 1986 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 ,
            "publisherid": "65bf6fec-13d0-45ae-8ee5-a6ed6a0203b2",
            "place": "kol" ,
            "publishername": "pub1"
        } ,
        .
        .
        .
    ] ,
    "id": "a39c572e-b8ae-40c1-83af-393b96c08938" ,
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

that is joining based on id in publisher and publisherid in people tables.

Need help with the query.

I have just started exploring rethinkdb and this is the query i tried:

```java
Cursor cursor = r.table("people")
        .merge( people -> r.hashMap("publishername", people
                .pluck(r.hashMap("books", r.array("publisherid")))
                .eqJoin("publisherid",r.table("publisher")) ) ) 
        .run(conn);
```

I ran into the error: 
`Caused by: com.rethinkdb.gen.exc.ReqlQueryLogicError: Cannot convert OBJECT to SEQUENCE`

Editing to add the solution as promised. Hope this will help anyone facing similar problem.

```
 Cursor cursor = r.table("people").merge
             (
                per ->  r.hashMap("booklist",r.table("people").get(per.g("id")).g("books").eqJoin("publisherid", r.table("publisher")).zip().coerceTo("array")) 
            ).without("books")
        .run(conn);
```

I was hoping to hit people table once but this is what i could achieve this far. Scope for performance improvement. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I have just started exploring rethinkdb and this is the query i tried:
Cursor cursor =  r.table("people").merge(
     people -> r.hashMap("publishername",people.pluck(r.hashMap("books", r.array("publisherid"))).eqJoin("publisherid",r.table("publisher"))
       )
      )
  .run(conn);
I ran into the error:
Caused by: com.rethinkdb.gen.exc.ReqlQueryLogicError: Cannot convert OBJECT to SEQUENCE.

Comment: Hi guys , so far able to create the books object of the result document. Code is as below: 
     ArrayList cursor =  r.table("people").g("books").nth(0).eqJoin("publisherid",r.table("publisher")).zip().without("id").run(conn);
    Now need to merge it with the people table.Will update if able to do that.

Comment: Please never put more information into comments, always update your question instead. Or can you read what you put up in that comment easily ;-)